# Challenge from "leetcode162" to find peak element. Why this case can't pass?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

My code is as follows. I used binary search for the problem. 
38/58 test cases can pass, yet this can not pass any way:
[3,4,3,2,1], I calculated it on paper, and the process is as below:
end=4,mid=0+(4-0)/2=2,start=2.
But in the case above, start should be 1.

I don't know how to revise my code.

```
class Solution {
    public int findPeakElement(int[] nums) {
        if (nums.length == 0 ||nums.length == 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        int mid;

        //binary search
        while (start + 1 < end) {
            mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if (nums[start] < nums[start + 1]) {
                start = mid;
            }
            else {
                end = mid;
            }
        }
        System.out.println ("start=" + start);
        System.out.println ("end=" + end);
        System.out.println ("nums[start]=" + nums[start]);
        System.out.println ("nums[end]=" + nums[end]);

        if (nums[start] < nums[end]) {
            return end;
        }
        else {
            return start;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
nums[start] < nums[start + 1]
```

to

```
nums[mid] < nums[mid + 1]
```

but, your algorithm will work only when the array 'nums' is stricktly increasing and decreasing.

and

```
mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
```

is totally same with

```
mid = (start + end) / 2;
```

so i think it's better and simpler

Comment: It is not _totally same_. `start + end` may overflow.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just meant that both are the same in general situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a little over complicated, here is a more concise solution. If you go line by line you will realize that it needs less checks than you think.

mid is tricky, but if `start` and `end` set properly, you don't need to add the start val.

```
class Solution {
    public int findPeakElement(int[] nums) {
        if (nums.length <=  1){
            return 0;
        }

        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;
        int mid = 0;

        //binary search
        while (start < end) {
            mid = (start + end) / 2;

            if (nums[mid]  > nums[mid + 1]) {
                end = mid;
            }
            else if (nums[mid] < nums[mid + 1]) {
                start = mid+1;
            }
        }
        return start;
}
}
```